# cypress tests not triggered for a particular branch

Tags: cypress, github-actions

I have added github workflow and its corresponding yaml files in branch A, this branch also contains the package.json and other files to run cypress tests. I am planning on triggering these tests whenever the push happens to branch B, I tried adding the on Push Branch B, but for some reason this trigger only works whenever I move the workflow file to branch B.
Why is this happening and is there a way I can have the existing folder structure and trigger the scripts via workflow file

Comment: You're saying the workflow is not on branch B, but you want something to happen when someone pushes to branch B?

Comment: @rethabThank you so much for response, yes I would like to trigger the scripts whenever someone pushes code to branch B.

Comment: Hi @rethab 
I wanted to go with the recommended way. I added the workflow with on condition to the default branch of the repo. 

1. Quick question how does cypress know where to find the test scripts ? because they are in different branch as of default branch.

2. Do you suggest me to add all the cypress tests to default branch? example: my default branch = development, I want to run tests when someone pushes to stage branch. I have tests written located at "cypress" branch

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior. If you want workflow to be run on push in a particular branch, the workflow has to be in that branch.

You usually add workflow to your master branch so that it is present in every newly created branch and specify when to run it in `on` key - this is the recommended way and probably what you want.

There is however a possible solution to run action from a different branch. You can [convert workflow to an action](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/creating-a-composite-action#creating-an-action-metadata-file).
Then you need to create a workflow in branch B that will checkout branch A and trigger the action. Also, checkout to specified folder so that there are no conflicts.

Simple example:

workflow-in-b-branch.yml

```yaml
jobs:
  reusable_action_job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          ref: branch-A
          path: branch-a
      - uses: ./branch-a/.github/actions/action-name
```

Comment: Thank you @Ondřej Tůma 

when you meant the master branch, do you mean the default branch, I wanted to go with the recommended way. 

I added the workflow with on condition as you said to the default branch of the repo.

1. Quick question how does cypress know where to find the test scripts ? because they are in different branch as of default branch.
2. Do you suggest me to add all the cypress tests to default branch? 

example: my default branch = development, I want to run tests when someone pushes to stage branch. I have tests written located at "cypress" branch

Comment: Hello @Jarvis, usually the workflow is split between some main-staging-develop(feat/issue) branches. When you create your first cypress tests, lets say on develop branch, you should test them, and gradually merge to staging and then master. Maybe I missed the point of having cypress tests in separate branch? If so, please explain to me why do you have it like that

Comment: Dear @Ondřej Tůma,
Thank you so much for the quick response, I created a new folder in staging branch and have all the tests in that folder, we usually merge staging in prod branch after each sprint, is there a way I can refrain this tests folder in particular to not to move into prod when I do the merge into prod. ?

Please provide me your insights.

Thank you :)

Comment: Hey @Jarvis, why you don't want to merge cypress tests into master?